# update member of LitElement for the refreshing of the rendering?

Tags: frontend, polymer, rendering, refresh, lit-element

My extended LitElement class has variable members, the values of which could be changed at any time. The rendering depends on several of them. I'd like know, which update() member function should be overwritten for the purpose of refreshing the rendering updon every update of any modifications to the varialbe members.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to, LitElement manages that for you, and queues up multiple property updates to become one DOM update/reflow.

These are called [reactive properties](https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/).

You can set them with a `properties` meta property getter:

```js
  static get properties() {
    return {
      mode: {type: String},
      data: {attribute: false},
    };
  }
```

Or in Typescript with decorators:

```
@property({type: String})
mode: string;
​
@property({attribute: false})
data = {};
```

If these properties are internal you can use `@state` instead of `@property`.

Changing the value of any of these LitElement properties will cause `render()` to be called again. If you set multiple ones `render()` won't fire until you finish or `await` something.

Comment: My rendering is essentially realised in a callback function, namely, @onChange. This eventhandler won't be called in case there is no any modifications to the gui. How to trigger the onChange callback?

Comment: You can send your event from your control with `this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('onChange', { detail:..., composed: true, bubbles: true })` (`bubbles` makes your event fire on up through parent controls, and `composed` makes it fire out of shadow DOM). If instead you want to pick up native `change` events use just `@change` Lit treats everything after the `@` as the event name and is case sensitive.

Comment: this is not the case for complex models though - for list of dictionary/jsons objects for example - where you are binding to one of those elements. am i correct?

Comment: @mike01010 if you set a sub property on a JS `object` you don't change the reference, so `@property` won't automatically fire - you need to directly call `requestUpdate()`

Comment: thanks. yeah i figured that out eventually.  fyi, you can also clone and re-assign the property all together.